# 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'isoformat'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to annotate time field to sum the total time in a week in the following getting the above error

```
class StaffWorkTimeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%d-%m-%Y", read_only=True)
    total = serializers.TimeField()
    work_time = serializers.TimeField(format="%H:%M:%S", read_only=True)
    user = UserSerializer2(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = StaffWorkTime
        fields = ['id', 'timestamp', 'work_time', 'user', 'total']

class StaffWorkTimeSerializerView(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = StaffWorkTime
    serializer_class = StaffWorkTimeSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        week_start = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=datetime.date.today().weekday())
        week_end = week_start + datetime.timedelta(days=6)
        queryset = StaffWorkTime.objects.filter(user_id=self.kwargs['pk'])\
            .filter(timestamp__range=[week_start, week_end])\
            .values(week=TruncWeek('timestamp'))\
            .annotate(total=Sum('work_time')).order_by('timestamp')
        return queryset
```

Any help is appreciated to solve the error.

Comment: Please provide more information about the error (a stack trace or line number its failing on)

Comment: I think week_start and week_end are date object and you are filtering in datetime field. Try using timestamp__date__range=[week_start, week_end]

Comment: Please add the `StaffWorkTime` source code